# why can't delete the file?

Tags: linux

I am the root user of the system there is a file:

```
D:\XAMPP\htdocs\magento_41\magento\
```

which is under `htdocs` directory.

when in  `[root@localhost htdocs]`  i use `rm -rf D:\XAMPP\htdocs\magento_41\magento\`. it can't remove this file. how to delete it? thank you.

Comment: well if the user you're using has the rights to do the rm, then stop httpd before doing it :)

Comment: stop httpd? what's your answer meaning? thank you

Comment: forgive the shorteness of my answer. If you're under linux, reasons for not removing a file/directory usually are: no rights or some program is using them. since it's in htdocs, I suspect there's an httpd process publishing it, so stopping that will let you erase the directory. (and of course, in linux paths, the separator is /)

Comment: @BigMike Wrong. If a file is in use, it can removed nevertheless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
rm 'D:\XAMPP\htdocs\magento_41\magento\'
```

backslashes are special in the shell (escaping)

Comment: @BigMike That is **not** a windows path. `what's in a name` isn't a Shakespear file. Who says linux 'understands' paths? POSIX paths can contain anything except `/` and `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your path is wrong. When you're in `htdocs` dir, try using `rm -rf magento_41/magento`. Linux doesn't know windows' paths/drive names by default.

Comment: how can it be right ? linux path don't start with a drive letter. Are you sure is not a samba mounted path ? that seems a windows path to me

Comment: @BigMike: they don't start with a driveletter. But a file can start with D: just fine.

Comment: @sehe lol, didn't event thought about an actual file named "D:\something"